# Ubuntu 16.04 | Failing to create swap space error on installation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I am a new user to ubuntu, and I am wanting to learn it all, I am trying to install it onto my desktop computer as a full OS (not a dual-boot/secondary OS).

So i have followed all the simple installations of what ubuntu ask me, once ive finished the 3 steps into installing it, I am asked to do either of the 4 things (Erase disk, encrypt, use lvm & or something else)

I chose Erase entire disk as I am wanting to have it has a my core OS.
I chose the hard drive I wish to have Ubuntu installed on (500GB HDD), I click install now, and it gives me the usual write changes to disk, i go ahead and continue, then it brings me to the "Where are you?" sector of the installation, what then shortly I am greeted by the error message "The creation of swap space in partition #3 of SCSI1 (0,1,0)(sdb) failed". I am unsure of why this is occurring as its a new drive that I had purchased and Ubuntu is supposed to do all the partitioning its self.

I have done some extensive googling, and none of what I have managed to find that corresponds to the installation of what I am doing. I am installing Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 from a USB flash drive.

My computer specifications are:
AMD-FX 8320 Processor
16 GB DDR3 RAM
500HDD Seagate & 2TB WD Black.

I have also attempted to install the OS on the 2TB HD and have received the same error. I can do a live boot completely fine.
Any help is highly appreciated,

Thank you.

## Require more information just ask.

EDIT: I may of figured why the drive doesn't partition it gives me this error
"/dev/sda: unrecognised disk label"

I have checked for this error and found something: http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php#disk-unallocated, but it doesnt seem to do anything, I create the partition table, then create a prim partition (500gb) what i then try to create it (or apply it) it gives me the same "unrecongised disk" then resets the disk back to how it was.

Comment: Have you tried manually partitioning the drive instead of using Ubuntu's default partitioning method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem with 15.10. The solution for me was below:

---

### Partitioning Layout

Ubuntu requires, at ***minimum***, a 5 GB partition mounted as `/`.
For my 16.04 installation, I created a 100 GB `/` partition, and a 5 GB swap partition.

So, my partitions will look like this (numbers made up):

```
/dev/sda3: ext4: 100 GB
/dev/sda4: swap: 5 GB
```

### Installation

When installing, select the `Something else` option.
Then, click on the partition you created for `/`, and click "Change".
-  Check "use this partition", and for the mount point, type `/`

For swap, Ubuntu should auto detect it. All you need to do is select the swap partition, click "Change", and ensure it is used by Ubuntu.

### That's all!

The new partitioning layout fixed the problems for me.
I don't know if it was the simplicity, or the pre-made partitions, but 15.10 installed smoothly.
Hopefully it'll work for you, too. :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, how ever this couldn't help me, at the moment the HDD keeps getting unrecognised. I have added the partition table to the HDD, then I go to partition all of the drive, I name the label "primary" and then create it, after ive created it I get an error, libparted messages: /dev/sdb unrecognised disk label. Do I have to name the label something spetific or just name it as "primary" ive partitioned the tables and everything, but when it comes to applying the partition i am greeted within that error.

Comment: @OSKali are you labeling the disk or one of the partitions? for me, not giving any label has worked so far

Comment: One of the partitions. I do not know how to name the disk whats a little embarrassing. I have installed Ubuntu Desktop on my server (when I had it) completely fine, I am unsure of why its doing this now though.

Comment: @OSKali can you try deleting the current table, making a new one, not specifying any label, and see if it applies the table?

Comment: Sure, just to be sure, i do use the msdos partitioning table correct?

Comment: @OSKali if your computer is UEFI, use a GPT table. If it's BIOS, use a MSDOS table.

Comment: Ok, i have tried to create a new partition table, now it doesnt do anything, I have checked in the information area of the HDD, what gives me a warning "/dev/sdb unrecognised disk label". Anyway I could fix this? This drive is completely unallocated (no partitioning tables are on it).

Comment: Ok i have managed to fix it, everything is all good now, thank you for the help. :)

Comment: @SahibPrime... If a hard disk is larger than 2TB, it MUST be GPT.